# Why is my while loop stucked?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to replace two (or more) line breaks in a textarea but Its always got stucked in an infinty loop

here it is:

```
var dateinput = document.getElementById("date");
var intIndexOfMatch = dateinput.value.indexOf('\n\n');


while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){
    dateinput .value = dateinput .value.replace('\n\n', '\n');

}
```

Comment: I see some Syntax Errors here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you haven't changed `intIndexOfMatch`

```
var dateinput = document.getElementById("date");
var intIndexOfMatch = dateinput.value.indexOf('\n\n');


while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){
    dateinput .value = dateinput .value.replace('\n\n', '\n');
    intIndexOfMatch = dateinput.value.indexOf('\n\n');
}
```

better solution though

```
var dateinput = document.getElementById("date").value.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');
```

that replaces your WHOLE code, by the way